Using grouped exposed filters with contextual filters with query parameter default value
We've set up a date filter that we want to apply to more than one block on a page. We added some grouped filters to act as "presets," which work great when they’re part of a single block. However, they don’t work when we try to apply them to more than one block. To do that, we chose the “expose form in block” option and set up contextual filters with query parameters (?date=) as a default value for each block displaying data.
The issue is that the grouped filter passes a predetermined value (1, 2, 3, etc.) to the URL, which removes all meaning from the query. When we apply a contextual filter based on the same date field, the query ?date=1 doesn’t have any effect because it doesn’t correspond to any actual date.
Does anyone know how to get around this problem?
